# Why private set is not working to MutableLiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components

I have a code

```
var exampleData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private set
```

And I want to hide setter to value of MutableLiveData

```
    exampleData.value = "Hi!" // still working
```

I tried several ways, but all are working!

```
var exampleData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    private set(value) { field = value } // Working!

var exampleData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    internal set // Working!

var exampleData = MutableLiveData<String>()
    internal set(value) { field = value } // Working!
```

How to hide this setter?

Comment: what is a need of that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The setter of the property has no relevance for your `MutableLiveData`, as its mutability within the object itself. You'd have to cast it to `LiveData`, which you could be done with a backing property.

```
private val _exampleData = MutableLiveData<String>()
val exampleData: LiveData<String> get() = _exampleData
```

You can change the value privately with `_exampleData.value = "value"` and expose only an immutable `LiveData`.

Comment: I like the suggestion. But why not just do `val exampleData: LiveData<String> = _exampleData `?

Comment: @Rule That would be possible as well. But you'd end up with two different fields and a accessor. When you delegate to the backing property, you'll only have one field with that accessor.

Comment: IMO this do not works as intended, you can still call `exampleData` getter from anywhere in application, cast the result to `MutableLiveData` (as `_exampleData` is still of `MutableLiveData` type) and call `setValue` function: `(exampleData as MutableLiveData).value = ...`. This task requires something more sophisticated.

Comment: @bladekp indeed you can do this, but it's inherently unsafe. Even `map` and `switchMap` actually return `MediatorLiveData`. Since `LiveData` is an abstract class, not an interface, you'll have a hard time in achieving your goal in _Kotlin_. You'd have to extend `LivaData` with a private class within your scope and  make `setValue()` accessible to set the value. Since the class is unknown to the outer scope, you won't be able to compile any other cast. But the solution provided in the answer is sufficient for 99.99% of all use-cases. And in the end, it will not guard you against reflections.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [LiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData) and [MutableLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MutableLiveData) you can see that in LiveData `setValue()` & `postValue()` methods are not public. Whereas, in MutableLiveData they can be accessed. So if you want to make them not accessible, Change it to `LiveData` instead of using `MutableLiveData`.